# Shall I delete unused files created automatically?

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.5**

In the project there are unused files.
For example, I use Django login/logout function's but I have created a special login template.

I don't use: models.py, views.py, tests.py.

But I did register the app for Django to find templates.

Could you tell me whether I should delete these unused files?
Django style guide keeps silent on this matter.

Deleteing seems logical. But I decided to ask you just to be on the safe side.

Comment: The alternative is keeping files that serve no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need at minimum `models.py` (even if it is empty) in order for django to detect an application.

From the [documentation on applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/):

> The application registry is initialized in three stages. At each
>   stage, Django processes all applications in the order of
>   INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> First Django imports each item in INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> If it’s an application configuration class, Django imports the root
>   package of the application, defined by its name attribute. If it’s a
>   Python package, Django creates a default application configuration.
>
> At this stage, your code shouldn’t import any models!
>
> In other words, your applications’ root packages and the modules that
>   define your application configuration classes shouldn’t import any
>   models, even indirectly.
>
> Strictly speaking, Django allows importing models once their
>   application configuration is loaded. However, in order to avoid
>   needless constraints on the order of INSTALLED_APPS, it’s strongly
>   recommended not import any models at this stage.
>
> Once this stage completes, APIs that operate on application
>   configurations such as get_app_config() become usable.
>
> Then Django attempts to import the models submodule of each
>   application, if there is one.
>
> You must define or import all models in your application’s `models.py`
>   or `models/__init__.py`. Otherwise, the application registry may not be
>   fully populated at this point, which could cause the ORM to
>   malfunction.
>
> Once this stage completes, APIs that operate on models such as
>   get_model() become usable.
>
> Finally Django runs the ready() method of each application
>   configuration.

So if you need to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`, you need to keep `models.py`.  This restriction will be removed in a future django version.

Comment: Could you tell me whether this is a documented feature? Or it is just life experience.